# insert addthis links and joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

In Joomla 2.5.6, I create an article and use its link as a menu item, the article by default displays with print and email icons on the right hand side. I would like to add a facebook, linkedin, etc icons next to them when the article is created. I would like to do this for all of the articles I will create in the future. How can I do this ?

Comment: do you mean a facebook "like" button for example?

Comment: yes I do, it should be as small as the print and the email icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [shareThis](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-share/social-multi-share/8117) joomla plugin to have FB,twitter, mail and G+ share buttons on my website. You can find how to install it [here](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/446460-joomla-integration).

Answer (score 0):

I know that the [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/8061?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czoyOiJrMiI7aToxO3M6MzoiJ2syIjtpOjI7czo0OiJrMidzIjt9) component has Facebook, Twitter and Google+ buttons for each article however you could also check the Joomla Extensions Directory category for such plugins. Here is the category for the facebook buttons:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-share/facebook-share

I have never used Linkedin so am not too sure but here are some results from the JED search:

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=linkedin

Hope this helps